# How to use PROXY_LIST with password in Scrapy?

Tags: proxy, scrapy

I need to use different proxies to avoid being banned.

i read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345696/scrapy-using-pool-of-random-proxies-to-avoid-being-banned)  and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710483/scrapy-and-proxies)

i put my proxies in `proxylist.txt`

```
http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:port
http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port
http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:port
http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port
```

and i set it in **custom_settings**

```
class MyClass(scrapy.Spider):
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
    start_time = time.time()
    name = 'mySpider'
    custom_settings = {
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY'    : 'False',
        'RETRY_TIMES'       : 10,
        'PROXY_LIST'        : 'proxylist.txt',
        'PROXY_MODE'        : 0,
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES' : {
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
            'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy': 100,
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
            'scrapy_crawlera.CrawleraMiddleware': 600,
            'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
            'random_useragent.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400
        },
    }
```

this version **worked** when my proxies **had no Passwords**

Now i have the password for each proxy, how can i change it for working **with password** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer my own question.

I use this and it works:

```
http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@PROXYIP:PROXYPORT
```